# How to change text colour for a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I would like to know if it is possible to add a color style to a javascript variable?

What I am trying to do is on a canvas, I have a whole lot of different text (prizes on a winning wheel circle) and I would like each prize text to be a different colour.

This is my code so far:

```
var prize1 = "car",
    prize2 = "boat",
    prize3 = "cycle",
    prize4 = "scooter",
    prize5 = "jet ski";

var prizes = [prize3, prize1, prize4, prize3, prize5, prize4,
              prize3, prize2, prize4, prize3, prize1,
              prize4, prize3, prize5, prize4, prize2];
```

And these get drawn onto a canvas.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to achieve? If not, does anyone have any other suggestions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use object type instead.

```
var prize1 = {
   title: "car"
   color: "red"
},
...
```

in rendering cycle use `prize[i].title` and `prize[i].color` as you wish.

And I strongly don't recommend you use `var1`, `var2` etc.
Just create one variable with all objects:

```
var prizes = [
   {...},
   {...},
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, you can draw anything you like with canvas. Color is just one of the many attributes that you can directly use when drawing.

Comment: Thanks. Silly me. I forgot that with canvas you can use something like         context.fillStyle = 'blue';